# EditorFor and StringLength DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have the following property on my Model

```
        [Display(Name = "MyProperty")]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string MyProperty
        {
            get;set;
        }
```

and the following EditorFor template

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Template.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Data" runat="server">
    <%= Html.TextBox("", Model)%>
</asp:Content>
```

The problem I have is that the StringLength property (understandably), isn't being set to limit the textbox size. My answer is how should I be obtaining the attributes to set in my template?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between metadata attributes and validation attributes. `StringLengthAttribute` is a validation attribute, so you can't get it from `ModelMetadata`.

Luckily, [Wayne Brantley has done the hard work](http://blog.waynebrantley.com/2009/12/aspnet-mvc-2-beta-editorfor.html). Here is how he gets the validation rules:

```
IEnumerable<ModelValidator> validators = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.GetValidators(ViewData.ModelMetadata, ViewContext);
ModelClientValidationRule rule = validators.SelectMany(v => v.GetClientValidationRules()).FirstOrDefault(m => m.ValidationType == "stringLength");
if (rule != null && rule.ValidationParameters.ContainsKey("maximumLength"))
{
   var maxLength = rule.ValidationParameters["maximumLength"];
}
```

**Note:** if you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 or later, you will need to change `stringLength` to `length` and `maximumLength` to `max`.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer doesn't work if you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 or later. You need to change the keys used to get the value:

```
IEnumerable<ModelValidator> validators = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers
    .GetValidators(ViewData.ModelMetadata, ViewContext);

ModelClientValidationRule rule = validators.SelectMany(v => 
    v.GetClientValidationRules()
).FirstOrDefault(m => m.ValidationType == "length");

if (rule != null && rule.ValidationParameters.ContainsKey("max")) {
    var maxLength = rule.ValidationParameters["max"];
}
```

Comment: Big ups on this... Ran into this in code that was pushed to mvc 3 recently!